# Função de Play não funciona no navegador do iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, api-youtube

Essas funções abaixo são da API do Youtube para visualização de vídeos.
Está funcionando em todos os navegadores. Mas quando abro o site no iPhone e clico no PLAY para começar o vídeo, não executa a ação.

Coloquei `click`, `touchstart` e `tap`. Nenhum dos três funcionam.

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){
    player = new YT.Player('video-estoria-animada', {
        videoId: document.getElementById('video-id').value,
        playerVars: { 
            modestbranding: 1,
            version: 3,
            controls: 2,
            wmode: 'opaque',
            theme: 'light',
            rel: 1,
            showinfo: 1,
            html5: 1,
            listType: 'playlist',
            list: "PLA8fGhdnBVrGSjEYeCPozWTXGhRX2rdJ7",
        },
        events: {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var clickDeviceEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';

        //Estória animada play
        $('#video.estoria-animada > div.play-video').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); 
            e.preventDefault();
            player.playVideo();
        });

        $('#video-shadow').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
            player.pauseVideo();
        });

        //faz a mudança do tipo de video
        $('#change-legenda > div').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
            $('#change-legenda > div').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            // Pega o tempo atual do video para setar ao trocar
            var currTime = player.getCurrentTime();

            if($(this).is('.sem-legenda')){
                player.loadVideoById($('#video-id').val(), currTime);
                player.unMute();
            }else{
                player.loadVideoById($('#video-id-muted').val(), currTime);
                player.mute();
            }
        });
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', onPlayerStateChange);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    var evento = event.data;
    if(evento == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || evento == 1){
        $('#video.estoria-animada > div.play-video').addClass('hide');
        $('#video-shadow').delay(100).fadeIn(500);
    }
    else if(evento == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED || evento == 2){
        $('#video-shadow').delay(100).fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

---

Só para constar as atualizações que venho fazendo nesse código.

Fiz bastante pesquisas com o termo: **click event ios not working**. E li a maioria dos resultados. Muitos deles sugeriam colocar a seguinte propriedade no elemento do `click`.

`cursor:pointer;`

Isso seria o suficiente para corrigir o **bug** do iOS. Pelo que estou pesquisando isso não passa de um **bug**. Agora se é ou não é, não sei ao certo.

Atualizei o código acima também com o que está atualmente. Explicando o que acontece:

Em cima do vídeo tem uma `div` com um botão **PLAY**, que ao clicar nele a `div` sai de cima do vídeo e começa a reprodução.

Até no meu celular *android 4.2* funciona esse vídeo. Menos no iOS do iPhone 4 e 4s.

Comment: Diego se fizer isto `$('#video.estoria-animada > div.play-video').on('tap touchstart click', function() {
    alert("Play"); player.playVideo();
  });` O alert aparece no iOS?

Comment: Debugarei amanhã e dou o feedback, man!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, aparece sim o alert no iOS!

Comment: Eu percebi que em alguns iPhones funcionam. Outros não.

Comment: Diego iPhone é uma coisa né rs, preciso saber qual iOS não funciona, vou testar no meu, é o iOS8.3.

Comment: Exatamente... eu disse iPhone, mas estou falando de iOS. http://www.contosdatiasil.com.br - Vai em histórias animadas.

Comment: É um erro de segurança veja: `www-widgetapi.js:24 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin` e a API não carregou `recaptcha__pt_br.js:193 https://apis.google.com/js/api.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`, isto até consegue funcionar eventualmente em alguns navegadores, mas acredito que será um pouco difícil funcionar com este erro em todos, me parece que eventualmente alguns browsers ignoram os erros e prosseguem, já outros não. Vou testar mais conforme tiver um tempo.

Comment: Onde você consegue visualizar esses erros ? No browser do iOS mesmo ? Aparece no console do Chrome.

Comment: Eu vi no console do Chrome pra Desktop, no iOs só tendo o Mac, acho que talvez seja necessário o XCode.

Comment: Eu tenho o xCode e emulador do iOS. Eu já testei uma vez, o problema é que roda o vídeo. uahuahuh

Comment: Ta bem liga o cabo do teu iphone que não funciona o player, abre o Safari e vai até a opção Developer ou Desenvolvedor. No menu deve aparecer o teu Iphone, tipo algo como "iPhone Diego", selecione ele e abra o console do safari (acho que abre sozinho). No seu iPHone com problema no player tente reproduzir um video do site, provavelmente deve aparecer uma série de erros.

Comment: O Safari não reconhece o iPhone Guilherme. Não consigo ver o erro.

Comment: No seu iPhone vai até Ajustes > safari > Avançado > Habilite o "Inspetor Web". Conecte novamente o iphone no seu mac.

Comment: Aparece `unable to post message www.youtube.com...`. Igual no erro que você mostrou acima.

Comment: parece ser um erro de origem (bloqueio de segurança), talvez com iframe, vou tentar ver se encontro o problema mais tarde.

Comment: Editei meu poste.